# Problema con hilos/thread en java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy realizando un ejercicio sobre hilos/threads en Java, trata sobre crear un programa que ejecute 2 o mas hilos. La funcion de cada hilo es elegir aleatoriamente entre "cara" o "cruz"(simulando un lanzamiento de monedas) y ejecutar este proceso 20 veces. Cuando se esten ejecutando los hilos,y si coinciden; habra una variable int contador que guarde cuantas veces han coincidido los hilos en cada tirada. Mi pregunta seria como hacer para comparar 2 hilos(o mas) y si coinciden guardar el resultado en la variable contador;y como hacer para que se ejecuten en orden(Primera Tirada:hilo1,hilo2,hilo3...Segunda Tirada:hilo1,hilo2,hilo3) y que no se atropellen los hilos los unos a los otros. Esto es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora,pero no he conseguido comparar los hilos, porque el nombre de los hilos no cuenta xD, tiene que ser comparado el metodo cara_cruz(), pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

```
    package ej_stackoverflow_esp;

import java.util.*;

public class Ex_Threads1{
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        LanzaMonedas c= new LanzaMonedas();
        int contador=0;
        Thread t1=new Thread(c);
        Thread t2=new Thread(new LanzaMonedas2());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        
        
        System.out.println("El contador de aciertos es: "+contador);
        
        
    }
}
        
        
        

class LanzaMonedas implements Runnable{
    
    public String cara_cruz(){
        String coin[]= {"head","tail"};
        Random r=new Random();
        int num=r.nextInt(coin.length);
        String head_tail=coin[num];
        return head_tail;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            
            
                for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
                    String h=cara_cruz();
                System.out.println(h);
                }
                
            
            
        
    }
    
}
class LanzaMonedas2 implements Runnable{
    
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        String c=coin.cara_cruz();
        System.out.println(c);
        }
         
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacer lo que pides. No me termina de quedar claro si hay que implementar algún mecanismo en específico, por lo que he hecho un ejemplo, bastante mejorable, que usa mecanismos básicos de Java.

```
public class Main {

    final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2;
    final int NUMBER_OF_THROWS = 20;
    final boolean[][] THROWS = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_THREADS][NUMBER_OF_THROWS];

    public Main() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
        initThreads(threads);
        launchThread(threads);
        waitForThreads(threads);
        compareResults();
    }

    private void initThreads(Thread[] threads) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new CoinThrower(i, THROWS, NUMBER_OF_THROWS));
        }
    }

    private void launchThread(Thread[] threads) {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void waitForThreads(Thread[] threads) throws InterruptedException {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    private void compareResults() {
        int count = 0;
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1; j++) {
                if(THROWS[j][i] == THROWS[j + 1][i]) {
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (count == NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1) {
                result++;
            }
            count = 0;
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class CoinThrower implements Runnable {

    final int index;
    final boolean[][] results;
    final int numberOfThrows;

    public CoinThrower(int index, boolean[][] results, int numberOfThrows) {
        this.index = index;
        this.results = results;
        this.numberOfThrows = numberOfThrows;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; j++) {
            results[index][j] = random.nextBoolean();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results[index]));
    }
}
```

La idea consiste en tener una variable global en la que ir almacenando los diferentes valores, que producen "las tiradas" de cada hilo. En lugar de cara o cruz, he usado booleanos, que para simular, es prácticamente lo mismo.

Primero se crean los hilos, luego se lanzan, se espera a que se ejecuten, con `.join()` y luego se compara los resultados síncronamente.

Comment: No entendi bien por que en el metodo private void compareResults() en la condicion del bucle pusistes for(int j=0; j<NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1; j++){}... Si son 2 hilos no???por que el menos uno?

Comment: La comparación la hago cogiendo el elemento enésimo de cada fila; es decir, el primero, el segundo o el tercero... de cada fila. Y comparo dos elementos cada vez. Por ejemplo, comparo el primer elemento de la primera fila con el primer elemento de la segunda fila, por ello, mi condición tiene que ser hilos - 1, porque, sino, llegaría a la última fila e intentaría comparar una fila extra que no existe, obteniendo un error.

Comment: ya pero si en la variable NUMBER_OF_THREADS almacenas 2, si en la condicion del bucle:  j<NUMBER_OF_THREADS-1, estarias  comparando solo 1 no?, o es que la posicion 0 cuenta como un hilo.